# cambiar hora de libreria obtenida por moment javascript por hora del servidor en libreria fullcalendar

Tags: php, javascript, fullcalendar

En lo que tengo problemas es en cambiar esta linea de código que me trae la hora actual de la pc, la necesito cambiar por la hora del servidor para que el dia pasado no pueda ser cambiado por el usuario , solo por mi.

esta es la que usa javascript

```
 defaultDate: yyyy+"-"+mm+"-"+dd,
```

para hacer la de php creo mi variable hoy que contiene el formato de la hora requerida 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus');
$hoy = date("YYYY-MM-DD");
y en el constructor del fullcalendar le digo que la hora predeterminada es

defaultDate : `<?php echo $hoy; ?>,`

y obtengo el siguiente error en la consola y no se muestra el calendario.
¿Cual es la manera de hacerlo?

defaultDate : 2018-Jul-Tue,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#checkboxeditar').click(function() { // este es el modal? no , esto es un checkbox que habilita/deshabilita campos 
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      document.getElementById("razondeeliminacion").checked = false
      $('.titulo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.importancia').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.lugar').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.motivo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fuente').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.hora').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.fotografo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.descripcion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.tipo').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.periodista').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').removeAttr('disabled');
      $('#btsubmit').removeAttr('disabled');

    } else {
      $('.titulo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.importancia').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.lugar').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.motivo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fuente').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.hora').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.fotografo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.descripcion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.tipo').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.periodista').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.etiquetas').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      $('.razonmodificacion').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  });

  var date = new Date();
  var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString();
  var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getMonth() + 1).toString() : (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
  var dd = (date.getDate()).toString().length == 1 ? "0" + (date.getDate()).toString() : (date.getDate()).toString();

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      language: 'es',
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay',
    },
    defaultDate: yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,

    select: function(start, end) {

      $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
      $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
    },
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element.bind('dblclick', function() {
        $('#ModalEdit #id').val(event.id);
        $('#ModalEdit #title').val(event.title);
        $('#ModalEdit #color').val(event.color);
        $('#ModalEdit').modal('show');
        /*
         $('[name="title"]').val(event.title);
         $('[name="lugar"]').val(event.lugar);
                        $('[name="motivo"]').val(event.motivo);
                        $('[name="fuente"]').val(event.fuente);
                        $('[name="tipo"]').val(event.tipo);
                        $('[name="hora"]').val(event.hora);
                        $('[name="fotografo"]').val(event.fotografo);
                        $('[name="descripcion"]').val(event.descripcion);
                        $('[name="reportero"]').val(event.reportero);
                        $('[name="etiquetas"]').val(event.etiquetas);
         */
        var form = hanyerck || $('#hanyerck')[0];
        var keys = Object.keys(event);
        while (key = keys.shift()) {
          //console.log(key);
          try {
            var input = form.querySelector('input[name="' + key + '"],select[name="' + key + '"],textarea[name="' + key + '"]');
            console.log(key, event[key], input);
            if (input.nodeName == 'SELECT') {
              var option = input.querySelector('[value="' + event[key] + '"]');
              if (option != null) {
                console.log('selcet====================================');
                //$(input).find('option').removeAttr('selected');
                //$(option).attr('selected','selected').click();
                option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
                // creo que era haci. :) veamos xD
              }
            } else {
              input.value = event[key];
            }
          } catch (e) {}
        }

        //console.log(event);
      });
    },
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // si changement de position

      edit(event);

    },
    eventResize: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc) { // si changement de longueur

      edit(event);

    },
    events: [{
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 1',
        start: '2018-07-01 07:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-01 09:00:00',
        color: '#beeeef',
        lugar: 'Lugar 1',
        motivo: 'Motivo 1',
        fuente: 'Fuente 1',
        tipo: 'Tipo 1',
        hora: '07:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 1',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 1',
        reportero: 'Reportero 1',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta1',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 1',
      },
      {
        id: '1',
        title: 'Titulo 2',
        start: '2018-07-10 09:00:00',
        end: '2018-07-10 11:00:00',
        color: '#ffbbee',
        lugar: 'Lugar 2',
        motivo: 'Motivo 2',
        fuente: 'Fuente 2',
        tipo: 'Tipo 2',
        hora: '09:00',
        fotografo: 'Fotografo 2',
        descripcion: 'Descripcion 2',
        reportero: 'Reportero 2',
        etiquetas: 'etiqueta2',
        razonmodificacion: 'Razon 2',
      }
    ]
  });
  //funcion para mover eventos y cambiarlos de fecha
  function edit(event) {
    start = event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    if (event.end) {
      end = event.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD ');
    } else {
      end = start;
    }

    id = event.id;

    Event = [];
    Event[0] = id;
    Event[1] = start;
    Event[2] = end;
    //console.log(event,Event);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'editEventDate.php',
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        Event: Event,
        title: event.title
      },
      success: function(rep) {
        if (rep == 'OK') {
          swal({
            position: 'top-end',
            type: 'success',
            title: 'Se ha modificado el dia del evento de forma exitosa',
            showConfirmButton: false,
            timer: 1500
          });
        } else {
          swal({
            type: 'error',
            title: 'Algo salio mal...',
            html: '<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp"></i>   04162910634  '
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

function mayus(texto) {
  let val = texto.value
  let result = val.split(' ').map(item => !item.startsWith('#') && item != '' ? '#' + item : item)
  texto.value = result.join(' ')
}
```

```css
.fa-facebook,
.fa-facebook-square {
  color: #3b5998
}

.fa-twitter,
.fa-twitter-square {
  color: #00aced
}

.fa-google-plus,
.fa-google-plus-square {
  color: #dd4b39
}

.fa-youtube,
.fa-youtube-play,
.fa-youtube-square {
  color: #bb0000
}

.fa-tumblr,
.fa-tumblr-square {
  color: #32506d
}

.fa-vine {
  color: #00bf8f
}

.fa-flickr {
  color: #ff0084
}

.fa-vimeo-square {
  color: #aad450
}

.fa-pinterest,
.fa-pinterest-square {
  color: #cb2027
}

.fa-linkedin,
.fa-linkedin-square {
  color: #007bb6
}

.fa-instagram {
  #color: #517fa4;
}

.fa-spotify {
  color: #1ED760;
}

#notification-icon {}

body {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url(http://prensaalcaldiadearismendi.epizy.com/img/imagendefondo.jpg);
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 940px;
}

.col-centered {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



<!-- Page Content -->


<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
      <h1>Calendario de actividades</h1>
      <div id="calendar" class="col-centered">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
  <!--notification -->

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalAdd" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="addEvent.php">
          <!-- este es para agregar los eventos , mas abajo esta el de editarlos -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo evento
              <div align="center"><span class="fa fa-3x fa-facebook-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-twitter-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-google-plus-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-youtube-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-tumblr-square"></span></span>
                <span class="fa fa-3x fa-vimeo-square"></span>
                </span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-pinterest-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-linkedin-square"></span><span class="fa fa-3x fa-instagram"></span></div>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="Debe ser corto" required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control" id="color" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="start" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Inicial</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="end" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fecha Final</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="end" class="form-control" id="end" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" required>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control" id="fotografo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; TODO EL EQUIPO</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso con detalles" required></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control" id="tipo" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control" id="reportero" required>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>




          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="ModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <form id="hanyerck" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="editEventTitle.php">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Ver/Modificar Evento</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="title" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Título</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control titulo" placeholder="Titulo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="color" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Importancia</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="color" class="form-control importancia" id="color" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONAR</option>
                  <option style="color:#000;" value="#000">&#9724; SIN TRASCENDENCIA</option>
                  <option style="color:#008000;" value="#008000">&#9724; IMPORTANTE</option>
                  <option style="color:#FF0000;" value="#FF0000">&#9724; ULTIMA HORA</option>
                  <option style="color:#40E0D0;" value="#40E0D0">&#9724; EFEMERIDES</option>
                  <option style="color:#FFD700;" value="#FFD700">&#9724; OTROS</option>


                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lugar" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Lugar</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="lugar" class="form-control lugar" id="lugar" placeholder="lugar del acontecimiento" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="motivo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Motivo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="motivo" class="form-control motivo" id="motivo" placeholder="motivo" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fuente" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fuente</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="fuente" class="form-control fuente" id="fuente" placeholder="fuente" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="hora" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Hora</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="time" name="hora" class="form-control hora" id="hora" placeholder="hora del suceso" disabled>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fotografo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Fotógrafo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="fotografo" class="form-control fotografo" id="fotografo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ANMAIRYS SALAZAR">&#9724; ANMAIRYS SALAZAR</option>
                  <option value="JOSE AGREDAS">&#9724; JOSE AGREDAS</option>
                  <option value="AMBOS">&#9724; AMBOS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="descripcion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Descripción</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="descripcion" class="form-control descripcion" id="descripcion" placeholder="describa el suceso" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="tipo" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Tipo</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="tipo" class="form-control tipo" id="tipo" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="ECONOMIA">&#9724; ECONOMIA</option>
                  <option value="CULTURA">&#9724; CULTURA</option>
                  <option value="SOCIEDAD">&#9724; SOCIEDAD</option>
                  <option value="OTROS">&#9724; OTROS</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="reportero" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Periodista</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="reportero" class="form-control periodista" id="reportero" disabled>
                  <option value="">SELECCIONE</option>
                  <option value="EVELYN CHAVEZ">&#9724; EVELYN CHAVEZ</option>

                </select>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="etiquetas" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Etiquetas</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="etiquetas" class="form-control etiquetas" id="etiquetas" placeholder="escriba y separe con espacio las etiquetas a usar" required onkeyup="mayus(this);" style="color: blue;" disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="razonmodificacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la modificacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <textarea name="razonmodificacion" class="form-control razonmodificacion" id="razonmodificacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la modificacion, si aparece algo aqui fue modificado el evento" required disabled></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group" id="razondeeliminacion" hidden="true">
              <label for="razondeeliminacion" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Razon de la eliminacion</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input name="razondeeliminacion" class="form-control razondeeliminacion" id="razondeeliminacion" placeholder="escriba la razon de la eliminacion" disabled pattern=".{15,}" required title="explique con mas de 15 letras por que desea la eliminar el evento"></input>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <div class="checkbox">Seleccione una opcion <br/>
                  <label class="text-danger"><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkboxeditar" value="checkbox" onclick="activarcasilla(this)"> Editar Evento</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label class="text-danger">
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="id" class="form-control" id="id">
        
         </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
        <button  id="btsubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Guardar</button>
         </div>
       </form>
       </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    
    
        <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     
     <!-- FullCalendar -->
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
     <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/4.0.0-alpha/locale/es.js'></script>
```

aqui esta el ejemplo

resultado de la primera prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo de esta forma:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus'); 
$hoy = date("Y-m-d");
    .
    .
    .
  defaultDate : <?php echo $hoy; ?>,
```

Comment: sucede algo raro , me redirige a la fecha enero 1970
pero cuando presiono el boton hoy , me dirige a la ventana de  hoy.

Comment: alli arriba actualice la pregunta para que veas lo que sucedio...

Comment: que valor imprime en dafaultDate?

Comment: Intenta encerrar el valor en comillas

Comment: este es el valor que imprime 2018-07-10

Comment: como asi? $hoy = date('Y-m-d'); con comillas simples tu dices?

Comment: no, me refiero a que encierres el valor asi: `defaultDate : <?php echo "'" . $hoy . "'"; ?>,`

Comment: ahora muestra el calendario se muestra en la fecha de hoy pero sigue sin usar la hora del servidor como tal, si le cambio el dia a la pc , este tambien se ve afectado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80004/discussion-between-juan-ortiz-and-alanfcm).